# php cookies related issue

Tags: php, wordpress

i create a cookies as

```
setcookie('sm_posts['.$key.']', 'value', time()+60*60*24*365);
```

for an array `sm_posts` and print these cookies in a `wordpress` page but if i click on a cross image then it will be delete but it is not working

```
foreach($_COOKIE["sm_posts"] as $key => $value)      
{
    setcookie('sm_posts['.$key.']', '', time()-60*60*24*365);           
}
```

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying the path as the next parameter.

```
setcookie('sm_posts['.$key.']', '', time()-60*60*24*365, '/');
```

Do this for BOTH cookie settings statements (and manually delete all your existing cookies).

---

But a better solution is to use the WordPress defines for this, COOKIEPATH and COOKIE_DOMAIN.

```
setcookie('sm_posts['.$key.']', '', time()-60*60*24*365, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
```

(Again, manually delete all the existing cookies)

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way

```
foreach($_COOKIE["sm_posts"] as $key => $value)
 {
    setcookie ("sm_posts['".$key."']","", time()-60*60*24*365);
 }
```

I think it because of your quotes

Comment: i have try all of these but sill i am not reached to my aim.i want to delete all cookies.                               foreach($_COOKIE["sm_posts"] as $key => $value)
 {
    setcookie ("sm_posts['".$key."']","", time()-60*60*24*365);
 }